# How do I get difference of two dates and henceforth difference from the result

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet where as in first row there’s two cells consisting date of joining and present day. I want to have the answer in “Years, Months, Days”.

Similarly, there’s another row with the same but with different years and I want to have differences of the two results.

Comment: Since neither Year nor Month have a fixed number of days, how do you want to define it for your transformations?

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there must be more elegant ways to accomplish this, but this is how I solved it:

[image]

**Formulas**

B2 & B3

```
=TODAY()
```

C2

```
=DATEDIF(A3,B3,"Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF(A3,B3,"YM") & " Months, " &I7& " Days"
```

C3

```
=DATEDIF(A4,B4,"Y") & " Years, " & DATEDIF(A4,B4,"YM") & " Months, " & I8 & " Days"
```

C4

```
=E6&" Years, "&E9&" Months, "&E12&" Days"
```

E2

```
=TEXTSPLIT(C2,", ")
```

E3

```
=TEXTSPLIT(C3,", ")
```

E6

```
=TEXTBEFORE(E3," Y")-TEXTBEFORE(E2," Y")
```

E9

```
=TEXTBEFORE(F3," M")-TEXTBEFORE(F2," M")
```

E12

```
=TEXTBEFORE(G3," D")-TEXTBEFORE(G2," D")
```

I3

```
=DATEDIF($A3,$B3,"y")
```

I4

```
=DATEDIF($A4,$B4,"y")
```

J3

```
=DATEDIF($A3,$B3,"ym")
```

J4

```
=DATEDIF($A4,$B4,"ym")
```

I7

```
=TEXT((B3-EDATE(A3,(I3*12)+J3)),"d")
```

I8

```
=TEXT((B4-EDATE(A4,(I4*12)+J4)),"d")
```

Comment: I don't believe this answers the OP's question. And please post your formulas as text which can be copy/pasted.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Updated.  Can you please explain what part is not answered?

Comment: Your initial post did not show formulas for column `C`

Comment: Your formula returns an odd result with certain inputs: eg: `A2: 1/31/2022; A2: 3/1/2023` => `1 Years, 1 Months, -2 Days`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Can you clarify, which is A2?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I forgot to include `B2:B3`, I've updated my answer, but those contain `TODAY()`; therefore, your date 03/01/2023 (past present day) is not a valid input.

Comment: Sorry, those dates should be A2 and B2, i.e. Date Joined and Present Day  `1/31/2022` and `3/1/2023`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142401/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-arctiic).

Comment: I've made some edits to mitigate an issue @RonRosenfeld brought to my attention.

Comment: Note that in the picture, `B2:B3` were changed to an arbitrary date for testing purposes, for OP's described use you would use `=TODAY()` instead.

Comment: I would still disagree with the results you show in your picture:  `1/31/2022 - 3/1/2023` should, IMO, evaluate to `1 Year, 1 Month, 1 Day`, and `1/20/2021 - 3/15/2023` should evaluate to `2 Years, 1 Month, 23 Days`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Okay, I'm pretty sure I've fixed it **for good** this time!  Double check my work, please?  I was able to get the same calculation results as you, at least.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The differences seem to be correct, but the ΔDifference is AFU. For example, given `Row3:= 3/21/2019 : 3/1/2023` and `Row 4:= 1/19/2023 ; 3/1/2023`, ΔDifference = `-3 Years, -10 Months, 2 Days`. Depending on how the OP defines a year and a month, I would think the desired result would be `3 years, 9 months, 30 ± 1 days`

Comment: @ronrosenfield Thanks for pointing that out, I've yet to take a look as I'm currently occupied with work-related tasks, but I'll come back to correct it when I'm able.  Once I make (what I hope to be) the final edit, I'll put another comment up.